# GlobalCredit Class

Tags: java

Can someone help me with this?

```
GlobalCredit credit1 = new GlobalCredit().getRandom();
GlobalCredit rewardCards = new GlobalCredit();
```

this is the class.

http://www.cse.yorku.ca/common/type/api/type/lib/GlobalCredit.html

When I print credit1 and/or rewardCards, they both output a random amount every single time. isnt rewardCards suppose to be empty?

Comment: How would we know? You need to speak with the authors of this package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into `toString()` method of `GlobalCredit` class.

```
System.out.println(credit1)
```

above statement prints `credit1.toString()`

As per doc

```
the string "Global Credit Company [title]: CARDS=xx" , where title is the GCC's name and xx is the actual number of cards in the collection.
```